# Does my SQL query used to populate a drop-down make sense?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, cascadingdropdown

I'm relatively new to SQL - I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I added pretty pics. I have a query where I want to populate a parameter(based on another parameter that you input via a drop-down menu, which is the @ResponseRange var you see)

```
SELECT  
CASE
 WHEN crr.Name = 'Prescreens'  THEN  null
ELSE crr.Codes 
END
FROM      Client_Response_Ranges_for_SSRS_Respondent_Answer crr
where  crr.Codes  = @ResponseRange;
```

This is how that crr tables looks(it was just custom table for query):

[image]
[image]

ResponseRange
[image]

More info: so I have 6 parameters, and they are

```
BeginDate

EndDAte

SurveyID

SupplierID

ResponseRange

ClientResponseRange
```

The thing is that ClientResponseRange depends on ResponseRange - so actually ClientResponseRange is hidden. For all the choices of ResponseRange except one, I will automatically use whatever ResponseRange's value for ClientResponseRange. I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.. thanks very much any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your query is trying to check for `NULL = NULL`

Add this to your query, if that is what you want to do:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

However, there are some ambiguties with your query:

1. Why is the Value of Codes for "Prescreens" showing as NULL in the table, by "3" in the property page?
2. If you are trying to populate @ResponseRange with the query output, then where is the parameter declared?
3. Also, the approach to populate this variable is incorrect.
4. If the variable is pre-populated, could you also tell us how it is populated?

Raj

Comment: Hi Raj, thanks very much for answer.   So the reason it is NULL in the table is because the table is specifically created to fill the parameter named @ClientResponseRange . In order for my Report to work, it needs to pass NULL as the 2nd argument of a pair(i.e the pair ResponseRange, ClientResponseRange which go together) .

Comment: OK. Can you provide some details on where @ResponseRange is declared and how it is populated?

Comment: Sure , so actually I am  trying to populate ClientResponseRange , and the parameter   ResponseRange has its avail. values hard-coded (as shown in the 2nd picture). Thanks alot!

Comment: On the back-end @ResponseRange is this: `@ResponseRange VARCHAR(64) = null` and it gets parsed (commas are taken out from the big string '20,21,22...120' etc

Comment: OK I think I see what you're asking.  So here's the context: I'm working to migrate my company's Reports from a web-application format(i.e a .NET stack with the ASPX page that generates C# and then the user downloads a table in XLS format) to purely SSRS , which means I have to port some of the backend logic (like the business of parameter passing) to SSRS. But it's a stored-procedure that does the bulk of work, and it splits the commas - `SELECT CONVERT(INT, val) FROM dbo.Split(@ClientResponseRange, ',')` , along with all the rest of logic

Comment: If commas are taken out, then how will there ever be a row of data that satisfies the Where clause?

Comment: Good Q .  OK, so that is because the stored-procedure is called only at the very end - i.e it will get called like so: `exec [dbo].[prc_RPT_Respondent_Answer] '20121011', '20121017' , 18964 , null,  "30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,130",  "30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,130"`  - i mean that the previous is how I'd manually via SSMS run the report

Comment: I think I am getting it. What still confuses me is this - you are passing a comma seperated string in the where clause and using the output to populate a variable. So, the input and output will be the same. So, why?

Comment: I see what you're saying. OK I will study this and get back to you - thanks very much for answer

Answer (score 3):

I think I see what you're trying to do.  I suggest you change your query to something like this:

```
SELECT  
CASE
WHEN crr.Name = 'Prescreens'  THEN  null
ELSE crr.Codes 
END
FROM      Client_Response_Ranges_for_SSRS_Respondent_Answer crr
WHERE  (@ClientResponseRange = 'All')
    OR (@ClientResponseRange = 'Completes' AND crr.Codes IN (10,11,12 /* etc... */ )
    OR (@ClientResponseRange = 'Over Quota' AND crr.Codes IN (40,42,43 /* etc... */ )
  /* etc ... put the rest of your cases here */
```

You can then probably just get rid of the ResponseRange variable.

An even better solution would be to have a table in your database such as:

```
CREATE TABLE CodesAndResponses (
  CodeID INT,
  ResponseRange VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO CodesAndResponses VALUES ('Completes', 10)
INSERT INTO CodesAndResponses VALUES ('Completes', 11)
--etc...
```

And then just join to that in your query.  This would allow you to manage what codes correspond to what category without having to change the query in your report.

Comment: Thank you very much! , I'm trying this now

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but it looks like ResponseRange is a list of values in which case you need an in clause like this.

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN crr.Name = 'Prescreens' THEN null 
          ELSE crr.Codes 
       END 
FROM Client_Response_Ranges_for_SSRS_Respondent_Answer crr 
where crr.Codes IN (@ResponseRange);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. So It looks like it's stil not working. I will add a screenshot of my table . I need to match exactly because you choose one of six choices.

Comment: In SQL Server, this would only work if the literal value of `@ResponseRange` matched the value of the Codes field in a row.  Such as if `@ResponseRange` was '1,2,3'  there would have to be a Code '1,2,3' - it wouldn't look for code 1, 2, or 3.  There's unfortunately not a great way to do that in SQL Server without resorting to an elaborate parsing method such as using XML functions or a tally table.